# Passing grep as an if condition

Tags: shell, if-statement, grep

Hello I am trying to pass grep as an if condition. That is if grep matches the expression, then I will print the file name and the line number of the file. so far i have this:

```
for javaFile in `ls -f *.java` ; do
  if  grep -q '^[^/]{2}.*https' $javaFile || grep -q '^[^/]{2}.*http' $javaFile ;
  then
   echo "The file $javaFile has : " >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
   grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*http' $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt     
   grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*https' $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
   grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*ftp' $javaFile  >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
fi
done
```

But my output file is blank when I do that. Could I know why? :/

Comment: Replace `for javaFile in \`ls -f *.java\`` with `for javaFile in *.java`.

Comment: Never Mind, got my answer :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` needs `-E` option for extended regex and also you shouldn't parse `ls`'s output:

```
for javaFile in *.java; do
  if  grep -Eq '^[^/]{2}.*https?' "$javaFile" ;
  then
    echo "The file $javaFile has : " >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
    grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*http' $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt     
    grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*https' $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
    grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*ftp' $javaFile  >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
  fi
done
```

I have also combined your 2 `grep` commands into one using `grep -Eq '^[^/]{2}.*https?' "$javaFile"` regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
  for javaFile in `ls -f *.java` ; do
    if  `cat $javaFile | grep -rqE '^[^/]{2}.*http'` || `cat $javaFile | grep -rqE '^[^/]{2}.*https'` || `cat $javaFile | grep -rqE '^[^/]{2}.*ftp'` ;
    then
echo "The file $javaFile has : " >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
    grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*http' $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt        
    grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*https' $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
    grep -nrE '^[^/]{2}.*ftp' $javaFile  >> ~/Desktop/$1_externalServers.txt
    fi
    done
```

The out put is as I expected :)